# Entity Framework: include inherited class navigation properties

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following class structure:

```
public class Person
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

public class MarketUser : Person
{
    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class AdminUser : Person
{
    public ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }
}
```

and generic method:

```
public ICollection<TPerson> GetPersons<TPerson>() where TPerson : Person
{
    DbSet personDbSet = GetDbSet<Person>();

    ICollection<TPerson> personsCollection = personDbSet.OfType<TPerson>()
                                                        .Include("Orders")
                                                        .Include("Requests")
                                                        .ToList();

    return personsCollection;
}
```

and I am trying to use it like this

```
ICollection<Person> persons = GetPersons<Person>();
```

The question is, how to load the navigation properties of derived classes? In this case I had exception, because `MarketUser` does not have property `Requests`, and `AdminUser` does not have property `Orders`

Comment: That's right, MarketUser doesn't have property Requests, only Orders and Id properties is available to MarketUser. To have a correct use, move Orders and Requests to Person. Or create a specific GetMarketUser and GetAdminUser